# Move files in FTP with Logic apps

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

In an FTP I need to move files from folder to the archives file once they are deposited, I've build previous pipelines in Azure data factory, but since FTP is not supported in copy data I resorted to logic apps but I dont know which tasks to use. I also need to trigger the logic app from ADF.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement the workflow you are trying to achieve using the **SFTP/FTP connector** depending on how frequently the files are added and how big the file sizes are. And after that you can create the Azure Blob Storage to archive the files from FTP Folder.

Following steps would give you an overall steps which you should follow.

- In azure portal search **Logic app** and create. Open the **Logic App and under *DEVELOPMENT TOOLS* select *Logic App Designer* and from the list of Templates click on *Blank Logic App***  and search for *FTP – When a file is added or modified* as trigger.
- Then provide the **connection details for the remote FTP server** you wish to connect to, as shown below for SFTP server.

[image: SFTP]

- Once you have the connection created we **need to specify the folder in which the files will reside**.
- Then Click ***New step*** and ***Add an action***. Now you would need to configure the target Blob storage account to transfer the FTP file to. **Search for *Blob* and select *AzureBlobStorage – Create blob***.

Like this you would be able to archive the FTP files. You should also refer to this [article](http://mythoughtlab.azurewebsites.net/azure/using-logic-apps-to-transfer-files-from-ftp-into-azure-blob-storage/) to get more information how to copy files from FTP to Blob Storage in Logic App.

There is also an Quick Start template available for **[Copy FTP files to Azure Blob logic app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/logic-app-ftp-to-blob/)** by Microsoft. This template allows you to create a Logic app triggers on files in an FTP server and copies them to an Azure Blob container.

And for you second problem -

> I also need to trigger the logic app from ADF

Check this [Execute Logic Apps in Azure Data Factory (V2)](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/06/execute-logic-apps-in-azure-data.html) Microsoft document.